# How do I pass my webscraped information to a table in html code?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to make a web-scraper that will get data from corona-virus websites. I have made the scraper I was just curious as to how to pass that data I get to my html code. I know this type of website has been done before I just want to do it for my own personal enjoyment. Here is my python code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import csv

from bs4 import NavigableString

from flask import Flask


page_url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html

uClient = uReq(page_url)

page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

uClient.close()

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"callout"})

out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"

headers = "Deaths \n"

Deaths = containers[0].span.text

print(Deaths +"\n")

with open(out_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    spamwriter.writerow([Deaths])

html_file_smth = 'C:\\Users\\tshor\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\HTML\\Stats.html'

html_file_smth2 = 'C:\\Users\\tshor\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\HTML\\Stats2.html'

with open(html_file_smth, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as htmll:

    reader = htmll.read()

html_content = soup(reader, 'html.parser')

tr_tag = html_content.find(attrs = {"id":"use-id"})

tr_tag.insert(0, NavigableString(str(Deaths)))

with open(html_file_smth2, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as html2:

    html2.write(reader)
```

It says flask as an import but I dont think that is something that I need. Also, I know it is broad question but I am very lost so any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a separate module which does the scraping:

**scrape.py**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import NavigableString

def get_deaths():
    page_url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html'
    print ('Hitting URL: ', page_url)
    uClient = uReq(page_url)
    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
    uClient.close()
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"callout"})
    Deaths = containers[0].span.text

    return Deaths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    deaths = get_deaths()
    print (deaths)
```

You can now run this manually with `python scrape.py` or import the function to another module which is your flask app.  Of course this is only pulls a single figure. But if you did want to render this in a table you could do:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from scrape import get_deaths

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Create a list of column headers
    headers = ['Deaths']

    # Now the data, a list where each item is a list containing the row values
    objects = [[ get_deaths() ]]

    return render_template('index.html', headers=headers, objects=objects)
```

Which can then be rendered with the following template:

**templates/index.html**

```
{% if objects %}
  <table id='result' class='display'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      {% for header in headers %}
        <th>{{header}}</th>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for object in objects %} 
      <tr>
    {% for item in object %}
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}        
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endif %}
```

Notice that this avoids hard coding column names into the template file, provided you pass the `headers` list yourself from Python.

Run this with `flask run` and connect to `http://localhost:5000` in your browser.

You may also wish to have a look at my repo [search-generic-tables](https://github.com/vulcan25/search-generic-tables) which includes the JS library Datatables in the template to add things like search and pagination on the fly.

---

Be aware that the above code re-scrapes the site every time someone hits the page.  There are a few ways around this.  One option is to use [flask_caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so run `pip install flask_caching` and then decorate the `index` view function to define a timeout.

```
# ...

app = Flask(__name__)

from flask_caching import Cache
cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
cache.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
@cache.cached(timeout=50)
def index():
    # Rest of code.
```

Now the API result will be cached for 50 seconds.

Comment: oh wow. Thank you so much. I am just confused as to where to put this in my code. Is there any way I could email you. Im sorry I am very much so a beginner @v25.

Comment: @tshore please feel free to log an issue against that repo if you wish

Comment: where do I put this in my html code. I have a table for each country so where do I put this in a table.